# Directing to a new page after downloading a file

Tags: c#, asp.net, response.redirect

When I try to redirect to a new page after downloading a file it doesn't work. Do I have to remove or modify anything in this code? the debugger doesnt reach it

```
byte[] fileData = (byte[])sqlRead[3];

Response.Clear();
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + sqlRead[2]);
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.BinaryWrite(fileData);

Response.Flush();
Response.End();
Response.Clear();

Response.Redirect("Questions.aspx");
```

Comment: Ahmad, Could you please let me know how you solved this?

Answer (score 3):

Take out

```
Response.End();
```

[`Response.End`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524629.aspx) kills the entire response, nothing after that will run.

> The End method causes the Web server
>   to stop processing the script and
>   return the current result. The
>   remaining contents of the file are not
>   processed.

Comment: i removed it but now i got this exception:
Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent

Comment: Ah that is true.  Since ASP.NET uses the headers to redirect the user you won't be able to `Response.Redirect` in this way.  I would suggest that you take Steven's advice (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244621/directing-to-a-new-page-after-downloading-a-file/1244705#1244705) and use javascript to redirect the user.

Answer (score 3):

Andrew is right about Response.End stopping execution.  I don't think that removing it will help, though, since it would just affect the file you're sending.

You can get the effect you want with other tricks.  For example, you could use some JS on the page with the DL link to do a client-side redirect.

*edit*

What I'm suggesting is that you add a secondary behavior to your download link so that clicking on it both downloads the file and changes the current page.  It might work better if clicking starts a timer that does the redirect in a second or so.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not ASP guy, but you also need to move the Redirect call above any call that writes something to the body of the response.

Try to put the `Redirect()` call right after `Response.Clear()`

The redirect URL is transferred in header of HTTP response, thus calling it afterwards the body was generated (and thus the header was already generated and sent) would render in no effect or an error.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the response.end()/ It will abruptly end the request processing thread.

Comment: when i remove it i get an exception

Answer (score 0):

You could try removing this whole block:

```
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
Response.Clear();
```

I think the problem might be that the call to `Flush()` is causing content to be sent to the browser, so it is then too late to add the redirect HTTP headers that get added when you call `Redirect()`.

Comment: when i remove them all, the redirection works but the download doesnt work!!