# Enable button on ASP.NET after HttpResponse

Tags: javascript, asp.net, httpresponse

I have button on my ASP.NET page which calls gets disabled on click(to prevent double click) and call this function:

```
Private Sub ExportToExcel(ByVal nameReport As String, ByVal wControl As GridView, ByVal sTitle As String)
    Dim responsePage As HttpResponse = Response
    Dim sw As New StringWriter()
    Dim htw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
    Dim pageToRender As New Page()
    Dim form As New HtmlForm()

    wControl.AllowPaging = False
    wControl.EnableViewState = False
    wControl.DataSource = GetDataSource(False)
    wControl.DataBind()

    wControl.Caption = "<strong>" + sTitle + "</strong>"
    form.Controls.Add(wControl)
    pageToRender.Controls.Add(form)
    responsePage.Clear()
    responsePage.Buffer = True
    responsePage.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    responsePage.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" & nameReport)
    responsePage.Charset = "UTF-8"
    responsePage.ContentEncoding = Encoding.Default
    pageToRender.RenderControl(htw)
    responsePage.Write(sw.ToString())
    responsePage.End()
End Sub
```

Which I use to export some data to Excel. Now I need to re-enable the button on client side when the HttpResponse is finished. How can I do that?

Comment: Is this an AJAX call?

Comment: No i use a complete page refresh (Postback). I could not make it to work with Ajax but that's ok. I can live with that as long as I can enable my button.

Comment: Since the server processes the request, the only way it can be done is with client javascript, and I don't know if it's possible to detect since the request is a separate request than the original.  You could just use `window.setTimeout(function() { enableButton() }, 750);`

Comment: If your page isn't posting back under any other conditions/scenario, you could just re-enable the button inside of a `If Page.IsPostBack Then ... End If` inside of your Page_Load handler. Or maybe I am wrong..

Comment: @addam, I Can't do that because the button is disabled on client-side with JavaScript. Server know nothing about it

Comment: I have done something similar using [John Culviner's File Download](http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/).  This uses a cookie as part of the file download to inform the browser that the download is complete.  I used with with [BlockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/) which disables the entire UI instead of just one button.  You should be able to see how it works and modify it to enable the button.  Or just use BlockUI

Answer (score 1):

The Response.End() aborts the thread and sends the execution to Application_EndRequest. There is not much to do after that. 
Please check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778426/how-not-to-abort-http-response-c-sharp). It presents a solution using iframes.